# Why does SynchronizationContext.Post() get called only once when using multiple awaits?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, synchronizationcontext

Consider the following example:

```cs
async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task run 1: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    });

    // The SynchronizationContext.Post() gets called after Run 1 and before Run 2

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task run 2: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    });

    // I expect it to run after Run 2 and before Run 3 as well but it doesn't

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task run 3: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    });
}
```

I would expect a call to `SynchronizationContext.Post()` to be made every time an await operation ends but after overriding the `Post()` like this

```cs
public class MySynchronizationContext
{
  public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object? state)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Continuation: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      base.Post(d, state);
  }
}
```

Installed like this at the very start of `Main()`

```cs
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new MySynchronizationContext());
```

It only prints the message once, after the first `Run()` is completed.

I assumed that's because `Task.Run()` may detect that it's being called on a threadpool thread and just reuse the current thread but that seems not to be the case because some of my tests resulted in **Run 2** and **Run 3** running on different threads.

Why does the completion of an `await`ed Task only runs after the first `await`?

Comment: A functional SynchronizationContext ensures that Post() executes the target of the SendOrPostCallback delegate on the original thread.  It doesn't, so execution resumes on the thread created by Task.Run().  Which does not have a SynchronizationContext (it's Current property is null) so no more Post() calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext` method installs the supplied `SynchronizationContext` on the current thread. In order for the same `SynchronizationContext` to be captured and reused by subsequent `await`s, the implementation of the `SynchronizationContext` must ensure that the continuation is invoked on the original thread, or that it installs itself on any other thread that it uses for invoking the continuation.

Your implementation (`MySynchronizationContext`) doesn't do that. It just delegates the `Post` call to the [`base.Post`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs.html#16705ba05372139e), which invokes the continuation on the `ThreadPool`. The `MySynchronizationContext` instance is not installed on any of the `ThreadPool` threads, so the second `await` finds nothing to capture, and so the second continuation is invoked on whatever thread the `Task.Run` method completed, which is also a `ThreadPool` thread. So essentially you get the same behavior that you would get by using a properly implemented `SynchronizationContext`, like Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContext.cs), and configuring the first `await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out on my own.

The problem seemed to be my invalid understanding of capturing current `SynchronizationContext` by the `await`.

```cs
async Task DoWork()
{
    // This is still in the main thread so SynchronizationContext.Current
    // returns an instance of MySynchronizationContext which this
    // await captures.
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task run 1: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    });
    // Here it uses the captured MySynchronizationContext to call
    // the .Post() method. The message gets printed to the console and
    // continuation gets put on the ThreadPool

    // This await tries to capture current SynchronizationContext but
    // since we're on the ThreadPool's thread, SynchronizationContext.Current
    // returns null and it uses the default implementation
    // instead of MySynchronizationContext. This is why my message from
    // the overriden .Post() doesn't get printed which made me believe
    // that it didn't call .Post() at all. It did, just not my .Post()
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task run 2: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    });
    // .Post() gets called on the default SynchronizationContext

    // Again, we're on the ThreadPool's thread,
    // so the default SynchronizationContext gets captured
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task run 3: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    });
}
```